# How do I print how many times each letter appears in a string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a task to write a program that takes a string from a TextBox and prints how many times each letter appears in the string. Please note that this is to be in simple code.

Below is my code but my problem is that it cannot ignore the already printed characters. e.g. if the string is "aaaaa", it must just print one line that says "a appears 5 times" instead of 5 lines saying the same thing.

```
Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim tempStr As String
Dim a, c, k As Integer

For k = 1 To Len(str)
    tempStr = Mid(str, k, 1)
    c = 0
    For a = 1 To Len(str)
        If Mid(str, a, 1) = tempStr Then
            c += 1
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(tempStr & " appears " & c & " times.")
Next
```

Comment: Can't see a problem. Your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do. Try stepping through the code to see what it is actually doing. And try a few different test cases - that should make it clearer for you.

Comment: I understand what my code is doing and the question says it all. My post is requesting for help in making the code do what is needed to be done, not what I have made it to do. Posting my code was to show the effort I have made with the level of knowledge I have in VB NOT to say it is the complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update to address your comment:

The problem with your code is that you don't have anything to keep track of which letters *have been counted and printed* so that they don't get counted again.

To keep track of the letters used, you can use something like a `List(Of Char)` or use a Dictionary bases solution like the one shown below. But since you said you can't use lists or dictionaries, here's a workaround for you: Only count (and print) the letter when _it doesn't exist in the rest of the string (in the outer loop). That way, you guarantee that the duplicate ones will be ignored.

Here's an example that uses two nested loops similar to your code:

```
For i = 0 To str.Length - 1
    Dim currentLetter As Char = str(i)
    'Dim currentLetter As String = str.Substring(i, 1)  ' If you don't want to use Char.

    ' If the letter exists in the rest of the string, ignore it and continue.
    If str.Substring(i + 1).Contains(currentLetter) Then Continue For

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For j = 0 To str.Length - 1
        If str(j) = currentLetter Then count += 1
        'If str.Substring(j, 1) = currentLetter Then count += 1 ' If you don't like Char.
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("The letter {0} appears {1} times in the string.",
                      currentLetter, count)
Next
```

**Some remarks:**

- The usage of `Mid()` is not recommended. Instead, use [`str.SubString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) and if you only need one character, you can use `str(index)`.
- Similarly, `Len()` exists for backward compatibility. Instead, you should use `str.Length`.

---

### Original answer:

Use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary) to keep track of the letters' count and then display the count afterward:

```
Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim dictLetters As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)

For Each c As Char In str
    If dictLetters.ContainsKey(c) Then
        dictLetters(c) += 1
    Else
        dictLetters(c) = 1
    End If
Next

For Each pair In dictLetters
    Console.WriteLine("The letter {0} appears {1} times in the string.", 
                      pair.Key, pair.Value).
Next
```

**Shorter version:**

```
For Each c As Char In str
    dictLetters(c) = If(dictLetters.ContainsKey(c), dictLetters(c), 0) + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the code you wrote. However, my task is to be completed without using the reference to predefined dictioneries since we have not be taught that yet. We have only donr loops and nested loops in VB.NET 

Also if I cope your code to a new button, the line below give an error:

   `Console.WriteLine($"The letter {pair.Key} appears {pair.Value} times in the string.") –`

The character $ is said to be not valid

Comment: @BlessingHwacha If the character `$` is not recognized, then you're using an older VB version. You can replace that with `Console.WriteLine("The letter {0} appears {1} times in the string.", pair.Key, pair.Value)`.

Comment: This is a great answer, I've tested it and it works great - nice idea to use a dictionary. I have no need for it now, but will sure have a use for it in future - love the shorter version too. Worth an up vote at least.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops: the outer loop to select the letters; and an inner loop to test how many times the letter appears in the textbox string.

Your problem is that the outer loop is also selecting its letters from the string itself. By doing so, any repeated letter in the string means repeated outputs.

Instead, you should be selecting the letters from the whole set of symbols - usually `‘ ‘` to `‘~’`. But you will have to add extra code for those symbols that don’t appear at all: if the count is zero, don’t print anything.

Note that this is not a very efficient way to do it - you’re scanning the textbox string many times over - but it’s certainly fast enough.

Comment: adding to your answer john we may delete counted characters to optimize iterations in your solution.

Comment: That’s one optimisation: delete the discovered characters from the string as you go. You should then quit the algorithm once the string becomes empty: nothing more to do. However, that’s by no means the most efficient optimisation. Hint: data structures make algorithms more efficient

Comment: i totally second you in that.